# fbthrift (facebook thrift) stable release?

Tags: c++11, asynchronous, callback, release, thrift

Regarding the RPC package "thrift":

I believe this package exists in two forms: the "classic" Apache Thrift, and the somewhat newer "Facebook thrift" (or fbthrift).

I believe that Apache Thrift does not support asynchronous clients which make call that return immediately, coupled with a callback mechanism to notify the client that the server has completed its work. (My previous question, titled "thrift async c++ example" yielded a response confirming this belief).

I believe that fbthrift does a good job in supporting these things, particularly in C++ (and its C++11 variant).

However... my efforts to work with fbthrift led me to conclude that it is unstable as it's being changed pretty frequently.

Does anyone know whether there are stable "point releases" of fbthrift, and if so, how I can access them?

Comment: So, I can see in github that fbthrift has many tags (which correspond to point releases, I guess).  There was a big gap in the tags between "v0.31.0" (August 2015) and "v2016.09.26.00" (September 2016).  Does this mean I might presume that the August 2015 release was pretty stable?  Can anyone recommend it?

Answer (score 4):

Facebook released Thrift into OSS a while ago. It then went under the wings of the ASF, where it still exists as a TLP today. Facebook then later released their internally used version of Thrift again, containing some new features.

Since then, a number of features have been ported from fbthrift to Apache Thrift. Others are still being discussed. Although I can only speak with authority re Apache Thrift, as far as I know both projects are alive and maintained, and of course mostly compatible.

While fbthrift primarily focuses on what FB needs, Apache Thrift is the version with the broadest language support (last time I counted we were way above 20+ target languages). The last stable release at the time of writing is 0.10.0 from January this year.

Comment: Thank you for your input!  Could you address my concern about "asynchronous clients" and "non-blocking servers"?  My MAIN GOAL is to find an easy way to implement these things via Thrift using C++ (or C++11).  Any pointer to an easy example of these two things with cpp client and server would be MUCH appreciated...

Comment: Is there some sort of roadmap for Apache Thrift? It seems "dead" to me even though it's still being maintained. Reason why I say that is because 1) almost nobody blogs about it. 2) Really old YouTube videos. 3) No books. Ultimately, it feels like an abandoned project.

Comment: @sivabudh "No books." is not true, look at Manning. "No roadmap" and "dead" is not quite the same. No, it's alive! And blogging and YT vids ... what kind of measure is that? I'd recommend to ask on the dev mailing list if you want more info regarding current developments. It's a bit OT here.